# Python flask api routes 404 Not found error

Tags: python, flask

As the title of the question says, all the routes which are not in the main file i.e. `app.py` are throwing `Not Found 404` error. Below are the details of my small project:

Directory structure:

```
server
  -> user
    -> __init__.py
    -> models.py
    -> routes.py
  -> app.py
  -> __init__.py
```

`app.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from user import routes

@app.route('/') # THIS ROUTE WORKS
def index():
  return '<h1>HOME</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

`routes.py`:

```py
from app import app

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET']) # THIS DOESN'T WORK - 404 NOT FOUND ERROR
def register_user():
  return '<h1>Register a user!</h1>'
```

I cannot find out what is wrong here, I also tried the `Blueprint` method but I keep getting `circular import error`.

**EDIT**:

Flask Blueprint approach:

app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

mongo_client = MongoClient(mongoUri)
db = mongo_client[DB_NAME]

from user.routes import bp

app.register_blueprint(bp)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return '<h1>HOME</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

user/routes.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template_string
from user.models import User # if I comment this, it starts working...

bp = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@bp.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_user():
  user = User()
  user.register()
  return user

@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET'])
def check_user():
  return render_template_string('<h1>User Registered</h1>')
```

user/models.py:

```py
import uuid
from urllib import request
from flask import jsonify
from app import db # fishy...

class User(object):
  def register(self):
    user = {
      '_id': uuid.uuid4().hex,
      'email': request.form.get('email'),
      'password': request.form.get('password'),
    }
    db.users.insert_one(user):
    return jsonify(user), 200
```

I'm now getting this error as I mentioned earlier:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\project\server\app.py", line 10, in <module>       
    from user.routes import bp
  File "D:\project\server\user\routes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from user.models import User
  File "D:\project\server\user\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "D:\project\server\app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from user.routes import bp
ImportError: cannot import name 'bp' from partially initialized module 'user.routes' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\project\server\user\routes.py)
```

Comment: Please add in your user/models.py code

Comment: @ashwani added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first define a Blueprint, and then use that for your routes/APIs. In `route.py` write this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template_string
from user.models import User

bp = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@bp.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_user():
  user = User()
  user.register()
  return user

@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET'])
def check_user():
  return render_template_string('<h1>User Registered</h1>')
```

Then you need to import and register your blueprint. In app.py have this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from user.routes import bp

app.register_blueprint(bp)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return '<h1>HOME</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Have another file in the same directory as `app.py`, you can call it `extensions.py`:

````
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_client = MongoClient(mongoUri)
db = mongo_client[DB_NAME]```
````

And finally `models.py` will look like this:

```
...

from extensions import db

...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I tried this approach but got an error. I edited the question please take a look!

Comment: Please refer word by word to my answer.  It needs to be `@bp.route` AND NOT `@user.route`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is `bp` only in my original code, you can take a look now... but still it's the same error.

Comment: Can you please add a file `__init__.py` empty file to both `server/` and `server/user` folders. Let me know if it still doesn't work, cause this exact code is working on my system.

Comment: I edited the question, and added the `__init__.py` file, but still the same error. :(

Comment: can you remove this line and try: `from user.models import User`

Comment: Yes it worked! but I still need the mongodb stuff :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243121/discussion-between-sumant-agnihotri-and-regina-phalange).

Comment: Updated the answer to cover all files.